# Unable to instantiate activity- ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, android

My android application throws ClassNotFoundException Exception.

This is my code in MainActivity.java:

```
    package pl.advancedsoftware.manga;
    public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    ViewPager viewPager; 
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Favourites.context= getApplicationContext();
        SectionsPagerAdapter sectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager= (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(sectionsPagerAdapter); 
    }

    @Override   
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      //  getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="pl.advancedsoftware.manga"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" /> 

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="pl.advancedsoftware.manga.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="pl.advancedsoftware.manga.BookActivity" 
            android:label="Books" />
        <activity
            android:name="pl.advancedsoftware.manga.EpisodeActivity"
            android:label="Epsiode" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

My exception is exactly is:

```
> 04-25 12:28:08.868: E/AndroidRuntime(898): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 04-25
> 12:28:08.868: E/AndroidRuntime(898): java.lang.RuntimeException:
> Unable to instantiate activity
> ComponentInfo{pl.advancedsoftware.manga/pl.advancedsoftware.manga.MainActivity}:
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
> "pl.advancedsoftware.manga.MainActivity" on path:
> /data/app/pl.advancedsoftware.manga-1.apk 04-25 12:28:08.868:
> E/AndroidRuntime(898):    at
> android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2106)
> 04-25 12:28:08.868: E/AndroidRuntime(898):    at
> android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
> 04-25 12:28:08.868: E/AndroidRuntime(898):    at
> android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 04-25
> 12:28:08.868: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at
> android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
> 04-25 12:28:08.868: E/AndroidRuntime(898):    at
> android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 04-25
> 12:28:08.868: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at
> android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 04-25 12:28:08.868:
> E/AndroidRuntime(898):    at
> android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041) 04-25
> 12:28:08.868: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 04-25
> 12:28:08.868: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 04-25 12:28:08.868:
> E/AndroidRuntime(898):    at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
> 04-25 12:28:08.868: E/AndroidRuntime(898):    at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) 04-25
> 12:28:08.868: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at
> dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 04-25 12:28:08.868:
> E/AndroidRuntime(898): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> Didn't find class "pl.advancedsoftware.manga.MainActivity" on path:
> /data/app/pl.advancedsoftware.manga-1.apk 04-25 12:28:08.868:
> E/AndroidRuntime(898):    at
> dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
> 04-25 12:28:08.868: E/AndroidRuntime(898):    at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501) 04-25
> 12:28:08.868: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461) 04-25
> 12:28:08.868: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at
> android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
> 04-25 12:28:08.868: E/AndroidRuntime(898):    at
> android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
> 04-25 12:28:08.868: E/AndroidRuntime(898):    ... 11 more
```

I see that can be something wrong with path, /data/app/pl.advancedsoftware.manga-1.apk but I dont know. I want say that this project stop working after clone them from repository.

Comment: but noone has an answer which can works for me

Comment: try **clean+refresh**

Comment: Please post the complete stacktrace

Comment: I tried clean+refresh+build all, didt's help.

Comment: Can you post your full main activity code??

Comment: try this: just write android:name=".MainActivity" make sure you have (.)dot prefixed to MainActivity

Comment: I tried it, but android allows to use full path to

Comment: is there a manga.apk AND a manga-1.apk?!

Comment: is your /src folder in the buildpath?

Comment: <classpathentry kind="src" path="gen"/>
 <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check you are inheriting from `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` instead of `android.app.Fragment`.

Comment: Yes I'm inheriting  by android.support.v4.app.Fragment and i used it before, why u asking about this thing?

Comment: Did you try to import android.app.Fragment?

Comment: It previously worked, after change pc, and clone it from repo it stoped.

Comment: You are right, it was problem with this library, but second problem is how repair without write all graphics interface again.

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstall the app from your device, then clean  rebuild your project. In some rare cases restart Eclipse might make a difference.